# Changing the item renderer for a certain product in Admin area?

Tags: product, cart

I placed this in the custom layout section of my product:

```
<reference name="checkout.cart">
    <action method="addItemRender">
        <type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default_test.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Thing is, it doesnt not do a thing. When I edit checkout.xml and put my template there, it works. What am I doing wrong? I want to change the renderer in the admin area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Custom Layout Update` of a product (specified in the backend, while editing a product) is only loaded on the product view page, inside the `catalog_product_view` XML handle. Thus, any other controller (like `Checkout`) isn't aware of this updates.

So referencing the `checkout.cart` block (which only exists inside the `Checkout` controller) in the `catalog_product_view` handle, won't produce any changes to it or any of it's children.

If you want to use a custom renderer for a specific product, you can create a custom module that will overwrite the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` class and in the constructor you can check the product and set the template:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    if($this->getProduct()->getId() == [ID]) // or any other condition to verify the product
    {
        $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart/item/default_test.phtml');
    }
}
```